# Create an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

```
arr = [
    men: {name: "john", age:"30"},{name: "john2", age:"31"},
    women: {name: "kim", age:"10"},{name: "karen", age:"33"}
]
```

I'm looking to create an array with properties men and women, and each of those will have a bunch of objects. How can I do that in JS?

Answer (score 0):

First create object then array in it, so like this you can manage your data.

```js
 let arr = {
       men: [
         {name: 'john', age: 30},
         {name: 'john2', age:33}
       ],
       women: [
         {name: 'kim', age: 30},
         {name: 'kim2', age:33}
       ],
    }


console.log( arr.men[0].name );
```

just extend the value in the men or women array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need an object in order to achieve this. After this, you will be able to manage the `people` object just anyhow you want.

```js
var people = {
    men: [
        {name: "man1", age: 30},
        {name: "man2", age: 31},
    ],
    women: [
        {name: "woman1", age: 30},
        {name: "woman2", age: 31},
    ]
}

// Add to men
people.men.push({"man3", age: 32})
// Add to women
people.women.push({"woman3", age: 32});
// Print the people object
console.log(JSON.stringify(people, null, 2)); // pretty format
```